# How to change a filename when uploading with blueimp jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, filenames

Here is my problem.
I am trying to create a programmatic way (without the customer to input anything) for a customer to fill some web forms. For this, I have created a custom browser (which will be installed in customer's machine as a java application, using eclipse *swt with xulrunner v10.0* support).
 
One of these forms requires to upload a file using the `blueimp jquery fileupload plugin`. 
This file is hosted at customer's machine at a predefined directory (let's say C:\ as it's a windows-only based application).

I have used the following snippets:

Create file using javascript hosted at customer's local machine:

```
var myFile = File("C:\some_dummy_file");
```

and upload the file programmatically:

```
$('#some_form').fileupload('add', {files: myFile});
```

Everything is working just fine, with one exception:
The uploaded file has now name *'C:some_dummy_file'* (and not *'some_dummy_file'*) as it seems to include the directory that it resides. Unfortunately as the server applies file name validation, it rejects the upload as it expects only files with name *'some_dummy_file'*.
Additionally, as I don't have control at server side, I cannot change the file name at server side (I have seen some examples for these cases but these cannot be used in my case).
What are my available options / workarounds? Is there any way to change the name before adding (or submitting) the file?
Of course the way that I am creating the file ( `var myFile = File("C:\some_dummy_file");`) is just a suggestion, so any other suggestions that will resolve my problem are more than welcome.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Of course I forgot to mention that if it's possible to open an explorer window, browse customer's directories and select the file, that would resolve my problem too. But as I know this is not allowed due to security reasons

Answer (score 0):

The best for this is to make your images' names *unique random(approx.)* , for example, like this, using [guid](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID):

```
var myFile = File(guid);
function guid() {

  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```